# non-blocking mass-pinger for testing

Tags: report

I have an intranet system (no internet) and for verification I want an easy way to ping a few dozen hosts. I can run this on Windows 2008 Server or on Linux.

I want to get a simple yes/no report of if a bunch of hosts are up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a [bash script](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/monitoring/monitor-windows-linux-server-with-ping-script/):

```
HOSTS="cyberciti.biz theos.in router"

# no ping request
COUNT=1

# email report when
SUBJECT="Ping failed"
EMAILID="me@mydomain.com"
for myHost in $HOSTS
do
  count=$(ping -c $COUNT $myHost | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }')
  if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
    # 100% failed
    echo "Host : $myHost is down (ping failed) at $(date)" | mail -s "$SUBJECT" $EMAILID
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

ActiveXperts provides ICMP Ping and HTTP(S) page monitoring as part of their free version.  You can setup several different notifications for failures and successes as well.

http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/freeware/

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Which interface (GUI, cli?) do you want to use? Who and how will use it? and why do you do such pings? 
It is, if you ping for pinging also ping (hping or nmap) maybe a litlle scripted could do the job (but a machine replying to ping not necessarily is alive for the service that must give), instead if you'd like to know if a host is doing its job, then it's better to check for the services that it is supposed to give and to do that there are monitoring tools like monit or bigbrother (nowaday maybe also big sister) under Linux or you can use simpler system tools scripted to check the different services of the different hosts. 
I don't know under Windows.